# Мерцание заблокированного экрана при выключенной подсветке в Debian 8 Gnome 3

Tags: linux, debian, экран, gnome

На ноутбуке с Debian 8 Jessie и Gnome 3 имеется следующая проблема.

При выключенном заблокированном экране сквозь него можно наблюдать, как весь экран становится белым, а затем снова становится тёмным, и так с периодом в пару секунд. Эдакое своеобразное мерцание потухшего экрана.

Вручную что-то подобное можно увидеть на любом ноутбуке, если сначала открыть пустой блокнот, а затем клавишей отключить подсветку экрана (необходимо чтобы в комнате было светло), а затем сделать это же, но уже с открытым терминалом или любой другой тёмной страницей и сравнить вид экранов.

Как это можно исправить?

```
Ноутбук: Lenovo G50
Процессор: Intel® Pentium(R) CPU N3540 @ 2.16GHz × 4
Видеокарта: Intel® Bay Trail x86/MMX/SSE2
ОС: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) 32-bit
```

Comment: Дело может быть в железе, поэтому было бы полезно написать модель. Или же добавить вывод соответствующих утилит.

Comment: @user1056837 на ubuntu такого не было, это скорее что-то либо с самой Gnome 3, либо с её хранителем экрана.

Comment: Препираться правда проще, чем написать модель ноутбука?

Comment: @user1056837 весьма проницательны. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2325230 - это пробовали?

Comment: @user1056837 собственно это главная причина, по которой отказался от Ubuntu 14+ в пользу Debian, но проблема "заморозки всего экрана" немного другого плана, чем та, что описана в вопросе.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47370/discussion-between-user1056837-and-edem).